# How is a MySQL database properly connected to in NetBeans?

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans, connection, resolve

I'm trying to load a NetBeans project that is not mine. When I do so, I get a data source resolution error, so I right-click on the project under the "Projects" view and try and create a new connection to the unresolved database, which returns a connection error once the connection is tested. How do I fix this issue? Is it a problem w/ some other component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set the Resource in the GlassFish, so it can connect the mysql, Just look at the following link---->[Netbeans Help](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/web/mysql-webapp.html)